# I need help with KQL search query - I want to list peoples birthday

Tags: search, search-api, kql

I need a KQL something similar below to list users who were born in the current month

```
Birthday:"this month" -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople
```

The above doesn't return anything

[image]

When I look at the crawled property I can see as above it has been mapped to RefinableDate17
But I cant see this properties in Azure when i try to update my birthday.
Should i be abe to use a KQL query to do this and how can i get the birthday property to show in azure so i can update the birthday field?

THanks in Advance